# Adding a comment to a Fogbugz case using the Fogbugz API

Tags: python, fogbugz

In the Fogbugz UI, new comments are added to an existing case by clicking "Edit" and then entering your comment.

Is there a way of adding a comment to an existing bug via the Fogbugz API? I've been using the API in conjunction with [FogbugzPy](https://developers.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W199) and I can't find any mention of adding comments. Retrieving the last comment, yes, but adding a new one, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good old trial and error got me there in the end (aka I'm an idiot).

Adding a comment involves using `cmd=edit` and `sEvent`. With FogBugzPy, it would look something like this:

```
fb.edit(ixBug=145945, sEvent="New comment test")
```